# GemFire Query Debugging

Tags: gemfire, geode

The following link shows how to debug the `gemfire` query functionality - by setting a couple of flags. I've tried this and I'm really puzzled that it doesn't work at all for me. Here's the [link](http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric5/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.gemfire.6.6/developing/query_additional/query_debugging.html)

I'm passing them as jvm args like below:

```
-Dgemfire.Query.VERBOSE=true -Dgemfire.Index.VERBOSE=true
```

What could I be doing wrong with this? Or could there be some other property that's overriding this configuration of mine?

Answer (score 0):

K, I am also passing the following args:

-Dgemfire.Query.VERBOSE=true -Dgemfire.Index.VERBOSE=true

and the debug statements get printed:

Eg:
Query Executed in 51.678635 ms; rowCount = 1; indexesUsed(1):myIdx:1 "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM /my_region WHERE my_obj.my_val in $1"

Additionally I am passing:

-Dgemfire.index.RANGEINDEX_ONLY=true

... as well.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Passing `-Dgemfire.Query.VERBOSE=true` or doing `System.setProperty("gemfire.Query.VERBOSE", "true")` in Java during start up should be enough to enable the funcationality.

If the setting is enabled succesfully, you will be able to see something similar to below whenever a query is executed. Log line will appear inside the log file which you specify its location through gemfire.properties file.

```
[info 2011/08/29 11:24:35.472 PDT CqServer <main> tid=0x1] Query Executed in 9.619656 ms; rowCount = 99; 
indexesUsed(0) "select *  from /exampleRegion"
```

Corresponding Documentation from latest Gemfire
http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/getting_started/querying_quick_reference.html

Corresponding Documentation from Geode
http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/getting_started/querying_quick_reference.html